# How to substract two colums number in one table MYSQL

Tags: mysql

---

```
id ContainerSize  ContainerUsed  Result
1   40000          10            39990
2   40000          20            39980
3   40000          30            39970
```

I want get the result of substractraction **"ContainerSize - ContainerUsed"** in one table in MYSQL

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, are you thinking about query like that?

```
SELECT containerSize - ContainerUsed FROM table;
```

Comment: one more thing to ask. if i want to select the ID=3 , do not need id =1 or 2 ( if i have many id=3) , how should i write a query?

Comment: the output will be like 3 40000 30 39970 and 3 40000 40 39960 sth like that

Comment: @KevinTian just add `WHERE id = 3` at the end of your query. And read few tutorials about `MySQL` ;)